# How to encode a string into Json string text?

Tags: c#, json, encoding, json.net, jsonserializer

When I try to retrieve SQL table content in to a JSON format in C# eg: the content Baden-Württemberg is retrived as a "Baden-W\u00FCrttemberg" after JSON serilize. I try this

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
input = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);
```

But I get "Baden-Württemberg" I really want like demo http://www.percederberg.net/tools/text_converter.html, The input type is plaintext, ISO-Latin-1

```
Baden-Württemberg
```

and output type is JSON/Javascript/Java - String text

```
"Baden-W\u00FCrttemberg"
```

How could I do in C# .Net

Comment: you should use Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") , let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell JSON.NET to escape all non-ASCII characters like this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Baden-Württemberg", new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii
});
```

The value of `json` will then be:

```
"Baden-W\u00fcrttemberg"
```

And you can send the resultant JSON string through an ASCII-encoded channel.